# Add images to a database(access) using visual studio

Tags: database, image

I'm working on making a website to sell computer parts.  I am trying to display a picture along with some other information from a table in the database.  The picture column is OLE Object data type.

Some people have mentioned to store the images in the server and the url of the images in the database.  How would I achieve that?  Thanks

Comment: "I'm working on making a website..."  If this is for a production web site, then *DON'T use MS-Access!!!*  IMHO...  PS: Yes, it's generally a good idea to store image files on the server's disk, and just store the URL (e.g. filename and directory) in the database.

Comment: Why not? Not everyone is scaling a site for thousands of users. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: @paulsm4 i'm doing a small project for university and myself so thats why I'm using access.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli can you help on how to achieve that?

Comment: @Evan: The right tool for the job is seldom Access when there is going to be more than a couple of users, especially when there are so many free alternatives that work better. I wouldn't use an Access DB for anything, personally, even if no one was using it but me. :-)

Comment: Maybe not, but blindly saying "don't use tool x" without knowing anything about the project is silly.